# Include GImages in a Java Jar File

Tags: java, jar

I'm working on compiling all my code into one jar file, but I have many images that I need to include. Java doesn't include them, and I have tried a lot of different methods, but most out there are not suited for the GImage object. Is there a way to include these, or do I need to switch to icons objects?

Answer (score 0):

I can't really understand what the Gimage means. But I can read the image from jar file by below method:

```
java.net.URL imageURL = getClass().getResource("bomb0.png");
ImageIcon bomb0 = new ImageIcon(imageURL);
```

And then you can:

```
GImage image = new GImage(bomb0.getImage());
```

If you think this method is ok, you can have a test   ;-)

Comment: The problem with this method is that the GImage type cannot take in a type ImageIcon. You will always get the error GImage(ImageIcon) when you do this. Also, GImages are part of the ACM library.
http://jtf.acm.org/javadoc/complete/acm/graphics/GImage.html

Comment: Yep,but you can see the ImageIcon.getImage() in my answer and you can just struct the GImage using new GImage(Image).